# Assistance With Adding Multiple Dice Rolls

Tags: python-3.x

I am attempting to create a dice rolling application from scratch that will allow me to roll any number of dice and combine their values. I have figured out how to get the random integers to generate for any one dice roll and have assigned all the dice I wish to be able to roll to their own variables (d2, d4 etc.)

I am not sure how I would go about rolling multiple dice at once, then combining the value of the two dice rolls. I tried simply adding them, but adding together two dice rolls of the same sort of die simply doubles the value of the first roll and I end up only getting even numbers that are the result of the same number being added to itself so that seems like a less than optimal solution.

```
from random import randint

d1=1

d2=randint(1,2)

d4=randint(1, 4)

d6=randint(1,6)

d8=randint(1,8)

d10=randint(1,10)

d12=randint(1,12)

d20=randint(1,20)

d100=randint(1,100)
```

This is what i have so far.

I tried -

```
twod8=d8+d8
```

as well as -

```
twod8=d8*2
```

But they both simply use the first `randint` result and do not produce a second integer.

Comment: the reason you're getting that output is because, once sampled from `randint(1, 8)`, the sampled value is held on to in the variable `d8`. In case you need to simulate one more throw, you have to call the `randint` function again. Also you can write a small function with the dice number and number of throws as parameters to simulate such multiple throws

Comment: can you please accept the answer of it helped you? If not, can you please leave a comment?

Answer (score 0):

I was referring to the following function in my comment:

```py
from random import randint

def roll_die(die_num, num_of_throws):
    num = 0
    for i in range(num_of_throws):
        num += randint(0, die_num)
    return num

print(roll_die(4, 5))
twod8 = roll_die(8, 2)
```

Comment: thanks! I'm still learning so I'm not quite sure what this all means but ill get cracking on understanding it right away so I can see what's up ^^

Comment: @ZacharyBellard sure, don't forget to mark as answer and upvote if this solves your problem